# how to add new item inside show table active admin in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, show

how to add new item inside show table active admin in rails ?

i try this code :

```
show do |ad|
    default_main_content
    attributes_table do
      row "States : "
      row ad.states.map(&:name)
    end
  end
```

but the "States" not add inside table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please fix it in this way

```
 show do |ad|
  attributes_table do 
   row "Add States" do
     ad.states.map(&:name)
     link_to "Add State", ...
   end
  end
 end
```

Comment: how to show default with add states to show active admin @Rajarshi Das ?
your code just showing states only in show

Comment: you want lable Add states ?

Comment: hi @Rajashi Das, how to showing button edit and delete in show active admin?

Comment: yoou can render partial or link_to inside the block as I did

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to lose default attributes (database columns) just do:

```
show do
  attributes_table(*default_attribute_table_rows) do
    row "My new row description" do
      My row value
    end
  end
end
```

Your new row will be displayed at the bottom of the table

Comment: I don't know if the behavior changed later in AA, but to keep default rows working as before (with links to related resources, etc) I had to use `attributes_table(*default_attribute_table_rows)`

Comment: @llekn yo can write an answer to upvote you

Answer (score 1):

this is my code :

```
show do |ad|
    attributes_table do
      row :id 
      row :name
      row :featured
      row :url
      row :amount
      row :application_deadline
      row :accreditation
      row :created_at
      row :updated_at
      row :degree_type
      row :states_name do 
        ad.states.map(&:name)
      end
      row :description
      row :slug
      row :deadline
      row :degree_string
      row :image_file_name
      row :image_content_type
      row :image_file_size
      row :image_updated_at
      row :real_amount
      row :real_deadline
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to put them in the same row you can do this:

```
show do |ad|
  default_main_content
  attributes_table do
    row "States : #{ad.states.map(&:name)}"
  end
end
```

Comment: you have two `ad` variables, the code is not clear